# How to get parameters from the URL to the model in cakePHP?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

let's say i have:

```
http://some-domain/application/controller/action/parameter
```

This is somehow working in cakePHP. Now I want to now what exactly 'parameter' is. But inside the Model. How to get to this information?

I have to say that there is a formular including a 'Next' Button and I want to validate the input inside of the Model in **beforeValidate()**. But I have to know on which page the user was at the time of clicking the submit button. This page is 'parameter'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two type of parameter in CakePHP, you have passed parameters and named parameters. A passed parameter is as shown in your example and will be passed as part of the url.

```
http://example.com/controller/action/passed_param
echo $this->params['passed'][0] // 'passed_param'

http://example.com/controller/action/name:param
echo $this->params['named']['name'] // 'param'
```

I would recommend getting the parameters in your controller and calling model methods with them passed through.

Such as

```
$this->Model->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$this->params['passed'][0])));
```

As to how it's working, you will want to have a look at your routes file. In your `app/config/routes.php` you will find all the routing and which parts are passed.

The standard cake url format is usually as follows, as you'll see in the routes.
    `array('controller'=>'MyController', 'action'=>'MyAction', 'MyParam');`

I can't seem to find a specific page in the book on Params, but have a google around for guides.

Comment: In Cake 1.2.6, passed parameters are in `$this->params['pass']`.

Comment: Why `find('all')` instead of `find('first')`? Hopefully there's only one match when searching for an ID.

Answer (score 4):

`Router::getParams()` is available from everywhere and gives

```
    [plugin] => 
    [controller] => leads
    [action] => step1
    [named] => Array()
    [pass] => Array()
    [url] => Array(
            [ext] => html
            [url] => someurl/post-1
    )
```

http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Router.html#_getParams

Comment: good catch,
did't notice that, as we usually code stuff running after the routing is resolved as models, controllers & views

Answer (score 2):

Model (in MVC design pattern) shouldn't have direct access to any *external* variables. The proper way is to pass that variable as a parameter from Controller or View:

```
$myModelObj->doSth($getParameter);
```

Comment: that's what actually happens internally i guess :-)